# Integrating kal calendar in my application

Tags: iphone

I have religiously followed all the steps provided on the following link to integrate kal into my project. Everything went well with the steps but finally when I compiled my project (after adding the `#import "Kal.h"`), it raises a compilation **error: Kal.h no such file or directory**. I have tried this from iPhone SDK 4.1 and have really tried it many times so far. Your quick help is highly appreciated in this regard.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed with the 6th point as your include path doesn't seem to cover this file:

> Finally, we need to tell your project
>   where to find the Kal headers. Open
>   your "Project Settings" and go to the
>   "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search
>   Paths" and double-click it. Add the
>   relative path from your project's
>   directory to the "Kal/src" directory.

If you adjust it, it *should* work. Make sure to make the change for all configurations (debug, release, etc.).